# Can we use macro variable (e.g.gdp_growth) in a panel data?

Tags: r, panel-data, multilevel-analysis, stata

I am examining one country over a period of 10 years. I am interested to see whether GDP_growth had a heterogeneous effect on wages across people with different educational background. The code below show my model. My question is whether it is plausible to use the gdp_growth in this design? If not, is there any alternative?

In Stata:

```
xtset id year, yearly
xtreg wage age sex i.educ##c.gdp_growth, fe
```

In R

```
 plm(wage ~ age + sex + educ + educ*gdp_growth, data=df, 
 index=c("id", "year"), model="within")
```

Comment: Hi jad, can you please tag this question with the software you are using?

Comment: Does education change for a person over time? If it does not, the direct effect is not separately identified (it gets removed by the demeaning). The interaction coefficient may still be estimable, but it's not clear what plausible means here. Do you mean plausibly causal given what else in the model and some assumptions about how people choose their schooling?

Comment: Education does change in the model. If someone gets a university degree, hence an increase in their salaries later on, the model can catch it. So if i understood you right, it is plausible to put the macro indicator in the model? What i mean is, whether an economic expansion/contraction gives more benefit to one educational group over the other